# Rails hash counting from a specific keys in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, key

Hi I am using this code bellow

```
Companion.where(companion_type: 1).joins(:tasks).where(tasks: {status: 3}).group_by_month(:created_at).size
```

and i am having a data looks like this

```
Jan, 2017 => 89
     .
     .
     .

Aug, 2021 => 300
```

But i need data's above from Jan, 2019
Is there any nice ways to solve it out?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in Jan 2019, then you don't need to pull all the Companion table, and then group them by month. Instead, select only those in the month of interest...

```rb
Companion.
  where(companion_type: 1).
  joins(:tasks).
  where(tasks: {status: 3}).
  where("MONTH(tasks.created_at) = 1 AND DAY(tasks.created_at) = 19").
  count
```

I assume that it's the `created_at` of tasks that you want to filter, vs. the `created_at` of companions, is that right?

Also, it's better to use `count` than `size` because that is directly inserted into the sql, as opposed to instantiating all the objects from Jan, 2019 and then applying .size to the result.

Comment: oh i wrote absolutely wrong question... i need a datas starting from Jan 2019!

Comment: the data what i would like to know is how many Companion(companion_type: 1) has a Task, since 2019

Comment: I'm not clear what you want. In your example result does it mean that 300 companions had some task in August 2021, or does it mean that there were 300 tasks in August 2021 that belong to any Companion(type: 1)? Or asked differently, is 300 a count of companions or tasks?